# how to use izpack to make my jar application to installer?

Tags: java, izpack

I download and install izpack to create installer.But There is no shortcut icon to run it.Can any one tell me how to run izpack and how to create installer through izpack.(I have the jar file).

Answer (score 3):

Hello 
In the link below you will find a nice help about izpack installer.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=89

Link below contains a detailed pdf to make installer with izpack.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?attachment_id=112

cheers

Imran tariq

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in properly configuring the **shortcutSpec.xml** in **project-install.xml**.
Put the following lines in project-install.xml.

```
<resources>
   <res id="shortcutSpec.xml" src="c:\locationOf\shortcutSpec.xml" />
</resources>
<native type="izpack" name="c:\locationOf\ShellLink.dll"/>
```

now add the panel in to the panel stack.

```
<panels> 
 ...
 <panel classname="ShortcutPanel"/>
 ...
</panels>
```

The shortcutSpec.xml shall contain the details of shortcut.

```
<shortcuts>
 <programGroup defaultName="groupName" location="startMenu"/>
    <shortcut name="shortCutName" 
           target="c:\directory\file.jar"  
           commandLine=""  
           workingDirectory="c:\directory"  
           description="This will handle TimeCard Application"  
           iconFile="c:\directory\yourIconFile.ico"  
           iconIndex="0"       
           type="Application"  
           encoding="UTF-8"  
           programGroup="yes"  
           desktop="yes"  
           applications="no"  
           startMenu="no"  
           startup="no">  
     </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

If you wish to use windows provided icons, change the following attributes

```
iconFile=C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
iconIndex=x
```

// x can be any icon index number of your choice

Answer (score 0):

IzPack uses the command prompt to create installer and uninstaller for any java program. To create an installer open the command prompt and go to the IzPack installed path -> bin. Then execute the command "compile install.xml" here you should give the full path address of your xml file. Then it automatically generate the exe file with the same xml file name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The question asked before is not about'How to Use".But it is about how to add new Panel in the installer wizard.If you don't know the answer,Simply leave it.